# Creating diff patch using netbeans 7.4

Tags: php, git, netbeans

I have recently upgraded to net-beans 7.4 (PHP). Afterwards I have edited a php file and tried to create a patch as we generally do in net-beans Team > Export Diff Path & Tools Drop-down as well. However I am not able to find any option there. I have attached for where I am looking for.

Is there any way to create patch on net-beans 7.4

[image: Netbeans 7.4]

Answer (score 1):

That would only happen if somehow your sources aren't recognized by NetBeans as managed by Git (or any source control).

Export Diff Patch is clearly listed in [Git support specification for NetBeans 7.4](http://wiki.netbeans.org/TS_74_Git#Test_suite%3a_Basic_tasks).
However, it is invoked a bit differently:

> Select the project root node in "Projects" view and invoke `Team | Patches | Export Uncommitted Changes`... main menu action.
>   "Export Diff Patch" dialog shows up.

Make sure you have the mlatest version of the Git plugin in your latest NetBeans.

Comment: Would it mean if my project is not in Git version control than I am not able to export the patch?

Comment: @SukhjinderSingh in git, or any other version control system. I suspect that feature is conditioned by your project being versioned.